# set iterator to value with highest key

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I have a collection of strings with a score and I want to find the string with the highest score. Now, since `std::map` keeps its items ordered by key, I thought it would be a perfect storage class. Now I've got issues pointing the iterator to the last item (to retrieve the value with the highest score) . What I've got is:

```
int main(void)
{

    map<double, string> m;

    m.insert(std::pair<double,string>(79.43567,"ARH1265"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,string>(69.83569,"ZRE5265"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,string>(73.03261,"TA9318"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,string>(93.43567,"CRP5285"));

    cout << "size: " << m.size() << endl;

    map<double, string>::iterator it;

    for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
        cout  << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;
    }

    it = m.end();
    cout << "last element is: " << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;

return 0;
}
```

gives me an output of:

```
size: 4
69.8357 : ZRE5265
73.0326 : TA9318
79.4357 : ARH1265
93.4357 : CRP5285
last element is: 1.97626e-323 : ARH1265
```

when I expected to get:

```
size: 4
69.8357 : ZRE5265
73.0326 : TA9318
79.4357 : ARH1265
93.4357 : CRP5285
last element is: 93.4357 : CRP5285
```

why do I not get the expected?

Comment: end() is not the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`end()` gives you an iterator that is one past the end of the container.  That means the last valid iterator is `end() - 1` as long as the map is not empty.  Changing the code to

```
it = std::prev(m.end());
```

Will give you the last element in the map.

Comment: Or maybe `std::prev(m.end())`?

Comment: @lubgr Good idea.   I always forget about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I keep getting `‘prev’ is not a member of ‘std’` but I've added the `<iterator>` header

Comment: @cerr Are you using C++11 or higher?

Comment: @NathanOliver oh, yes, I needed the `-std=c++11` flag! Thx!

Comment: @RichardHodges Edited that in.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, utilize the [std::map::rbegin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/rbegin) iterator instead. It points at the last element of the non reversed map:

```
auto it = m.rbegin();
```

or:

```
auto it = std::rbegin(m);
```

Answer (score 2):

`CONTAINER::end()` doesn't point to the last element in the container, but the element *after* the last element - a sentinel value. That's why your output is some garbage value; you are just poking into a random piece of memory

Answer (score 1):

From [std::map::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end):

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container.
>   This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you have boost available, we can nicely check for an empty map and take appropriate action:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>


template<class K, class V, class C, class A>
auto last_item(std::map<K, V, C, A> const& m) 
-> 
boost::optional<typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::value_type const&>
{
    boost::optional<typename std::map<K, V, C, A>::value_type const&> result;

    if (!m.empty())
    {
        result = *std::prev(std::end(m));
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{

    std::map<double, std::string> m;

    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(79.43567,"ARH1265"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(69.83569,"ZRE5265"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(73.03261,"TA9318"));
    m.insert(std::pair<double,std::string>(93.43567,"CRP5285"));

    std::cout << "size: " << m.size() << std::endl;

    std::map<double, std::string>::iterator it;

    for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
        std::cout  << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
    }


    if (auto opt_last = last_item(m))
    {
        std::cout << "last element is: " << opt_last->first << " : " << opt_last->second << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "the map is empty\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, even with c++17 we can't use `std::optional` for this because std::optional does not support optional references.